# Match all urls path in array with preg_match_all

Tags: php, json, regex

I have my regular expression

```
\["([^_]+)"\]
```

`\[` -  Matches a "[" character

`"` -  Matches a """ character

`[^_]` -    Groups multiple tokens together and creates a capture group for extracting a substring or using a backreference.

`^`  Match any character that is not in the set.

`+`  Match 1 or more of the preceding token.

and this is work for simple

```
["Infant", "Kids", "Newborn", "Småbarn", "adult", "kids"]
```

but not works for urls set

```
["http://www.elodiedetails.com/storage/01C91C41AFB1E9E491CCB750D86948330B2EFFA95C33849C0127E5557380AF8B/b1e48c712dd94cc2b91d2ced7e40f7c6/jpg/media/245df3634bd045b4bbf7bdb003e5ab1b/zip_go-desert-weaves-elodie-details_50610135582NA_3_1000px.jpg", "http://www.elodiedetails.com/storage/FEFED8E72F7F2B4B1D546FBB8D10A7298C963A1F141EA55EFABA5B29B316D924/877cb34feaaf4560967081ef63716b09/jpg/media/08db7d4521704b35866b10b5f445cd5b/store-my-stuff-wild-paris-elodie-details-SS20-lifestyle_70650128580NA_web.jpg"]
```

I was to try example which returned result from [online regex](https://regexr.com/59e6k)

but this expression thrown for me syntax error

```
    preg_match_all('/\["([^]+)"\]/', $t, $matches);
```

how need to change regular expression for match utrls too ?

Comment: ```^_```  this expression is the problem. You say "match every single character which is different of ```_```. As your url contains ```_``` i think it's why it does not match".

Comment: Your string looks like a JSON array, so why not use `JSON.parse` first? There’s no need to hack together a regex with `\["` and `"\]` for that. Where exactly are URL paths being matched in the `Infant, Kids, …` example? Why do you exclude underscores?

Comment: @user4642212 noyp, `\[""\]` this regex not works

Comment: @shuba.ivan What are you talking about? Which regex doesn’t work? Did you try parsing your JSON? I suggested `JSON.parse` earlier, but I missed that this is PHP and not JavaScript. There’s surely a JSON-parsing function in PHP that you will be able to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regex, but why would you, as @user4642212 said this looks like an json-string. Which can be parsed by [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

In regex you simply do look for `"` then for everything except `"` and again for `"`.
But be careful this regex wont take care of escaped quotes like this `\"`.

```
// the "hard" way
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);

// the easy way
var_dump(json_decode($string));
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/p3RuH).

Pro tip: When you use regexr, set it to PCRE (top-right corner). This is what php uses.

[image]